# When is a topological manifold which is not an almost complex manifold algebraic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

When is a topological manifold which is not an almost complex manifold isomorphic to a real algebraic variety in the sense of locally ringed space?

It is well known that Serre's GAGA theorem solves complex analytic space and complex schemes over complex field.

Comment: A necessary condition is that manifold should be  smooth. In this case, it is also sufficient by the Nash-Tognolli theorem.

Comment: @DonuArapura Note that they are asking isomorphic "as locally ringed spaces", in which case the answer is, I suspect, never (e.g. because the Kähler differentials on a topological manifolds are always trivial). I'm not sure this is really what the OP wanted to ask though...

Comment: @DenisNardin Right. I simply ignored that since I wasn't sure what was really intended

Comment: complex manifold M， if it is complex analytical space, serre's GAGA thm solves . what i want to know for any topological manifold  is  isomorphic to a algebraic variety.